# Formulário simples de Django

Tags: formulário, django

Se eu tenho no meu *model* uma classe `usuario`, uma telefones e uma classe gerente, que são um para um, assim:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefone = models.ForeignKey(TelefonesUsuario)

class TelefonesUsuario(models.Model):
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=11)

class Gerente(models.Model):
    departamento = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(Usuario)
```

Caso eu queira cadastrar um novo cliente, como faço? (abstraindo layout)
Tentei isso até o momento:

### No forms:

```
from django import forms
from app.models import Usuario

class FormUsuario(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
```

### Na view:

```
def teste(request):
    form = FormUsuario()

    return render_to_response("teste.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### E no .html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.login }}
    {{ form.senha }}
{#    {{ form.telefone }} -> exception #}
    {{ form.departamento }} {# -> não aparece na página #}

</form>
```

Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como eu sigo?

Comment: Se você está aprendendo, recomendo começar com o Django 1.8 de uma vez. Neste seu caso, o `{{ form.departamento }}` não vai aparecer porque ele faz parte do model `Gerente`. O que você pode fazer é adicionar um campo `departamento` no `FormUsuario`, e após salvar o form criar um gerente com o departamento e usuário escolhido.

Comment: Oi. Sim vou me dar uma atualizada em Django 1.8, preciso mesmo! Quanto a Telefone, em Asp.Net eu faria normalmente uma grid dentro do formulário para adicionar dinamicamente. Já departamento eu inseriria normalmente e no code behind atribuiria no campo relacionado. A dica do campo no form me parece boa, mas ainda não sei como fazer para ter toda a inserção em uma tela só, então não sei como aplicá-la desta forma.

Comment: Se você quiser adicionar vários telefones você terá que usar `manytomanyfield` e não `foreignkey`. E essa `grid` seria no caso um `formset` no Django, onde sua view teriam dois forms. Veja na documentação do Django sobre `formsets`

Answer (score 2):

Esta pergunta é antiga mas mesmo assim deixo a minha resposta.

Neste caso pode-se criar um form só para adicionar os clientes e não o extender de "Model.Form". 
Em vez disso pode-se criar uma função "save" que confira e salve os objectos.

Neste exemplo, o form nem checka se o user ou telefone já existe nem tão pouco confere os passwords, mas serve como exemplo:

models.py

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefone = models.ForeignKey(TelefonesUsuario)

class TelefonesUsuario(models.Model):
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=11)

class Gerente(models.Model):
    departamento = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(Usuario)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.db import transaction
from .models import Usuario, TelefonesUsuario

class FormUsuario(forms.Form):

    login = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='login')
    senha = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label='senha')
    conf_senha = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label='conf_senha')
    telefone = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='telefone')

    def save(self):
        # usuario existe ?
        # telefone existe ?
        # password correcto
        # password_identico?
        # etc
        ...

        try:
            telefone = TelefonesUsuario(
                telefone=self.cleaned_data['telefone']
            ).save()

            usuario = Usuario(
                login=self.cleaned_data['login'],
                senha=make_password(self.cleaned_data['senha']),
                telefone=telefone.id
            ).save()

            return True, usuario.id

        except:
            transaction.rollback()
            return False, "Erro ao salvar cliente."


    def edit(self,id_usuario):
        # Edite o usuário
```

views.py

```
def criar_usuario(request):
    ...
    if request.method == "GET":
         # render form etc ...
         ...
    elif request.method == "POST":
         # get form etc ...
         ...
         form_status = form.save()

         if not form_status[0]:
            params['error'] = brand_form_status[1]
            return render_to_response('template.html', params)

         ...
         # continua para output
```

template.html

```
<form action="{% url 'criar-cliente' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```